# Why does an HP dv6 laptop get stuck on the bios screen?

Tags: boot, bios, hp-pavilion

I have an HP dv6 laptop which has been giving me few problems lately, before even booting to Linux/Windows.

So, I have a dual boot Windows/Linux setup, and the screen is stuck at the HP logo, with a text in the bottom (that shows every time) saying "Press ESC to pause startup". Usually, pressing this will prompt me to press either <kbd>F9</kbd> for Boot device order or <kbd>F1</kbd> for system information etc... Also, I can press these keys directly without pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Now, when it is stuck, pressing any will display a text like "ESC... Pausing startup" and it stays there forever. And if I leave it without pressing, the same thing happens, with the text not changing. The only way to get out of this is to press the power button, a single press (or 8 seconds does the job too).

This happens *sometimes only*, and after when I reboot, it boots normally, and sometimes it doesn't. I wait, turn it on, and then it does...

I had issues of overheating, but these are apparently unrelated. Few days ago, it got so hot, it shut down. I waited for it co cool down, and when I turned it back on, it booted normally. Today, it does this.

Is it possible that the hardware is damaged because of overheating? Is there any log I can check out to try and see what is happening when it hangs? I'm not sure that if I send it to repair, they'll be able to reproduce the problem...